# Android Pixel Device: Kernel path for CPU/GPU power consumption measurement

Tags: android, kernel, adb

I want to measure the CPU/GPU power consumption of the Android Pixel device.

What is the **`kernel path`** for the power consumption measurement? (I don't mean CPU/GPU Usage.)

Or not, is there any API for this function executable on **`adb shell`**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$ adb shell dumpsys power
```

to see power manager details. Mainly under **Drain stats** you may find the information you are looking for.